# Create Div with Absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, absolute

I wanna order div like in the image below any one can help?

All div has  specific width but they don't have Height restrict. There can be 4 div each column and next div (5th div) goes bottom of 1st div but space of top and bottom div must be same(margin:5px)

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/ is a good plugin for those type of things

Comment: i thought i can write a small javascript code and can do it. but it is looking hard. I will work on document that you gave.

Comment: but it will be best if any more easy way there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nathan's suggestion is a good one - there is also [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), which relies on jQuery as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in pure CSS, as it goes horizontal, as you progbably know. For a jQuery solution, check out a plugin like the [Columnizer jQuery Plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/).

Comment: There are any easy way coding with jQUERY?

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://stackexchange.com/sites it uses [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)!